# Adding location to Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a dataset with a few documents. Each document has many fields, three of them that are interesting to me are "time" and "latitude" and "longitude"

We say that a location in document is valid if the latitude is between -90 and 90, the longitude is between -180 and 180, and they are not both zero at the same time.

I want to write a query, grouped by time with one hour interval, that displays how many documents of each type do we have for each interval.

I wrote this

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": 
  {
    "docs_per_hour": 
    {
      "date_histogram": 
      {
        "field": "time",
        "interval": "hour",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and when I run it, it prints several things like

```
{
  "key_as_string" : "2020-04-19 01:00:00",
  "key" : 1587258000000,
  "doc_count" : 14
}
```

Instead of doc_count, I would like to have doc_with_location_count and doc_without_location_count.

How do I write that aggregation

Comment: Could you please share your mapping? That would be useful.

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean. There's no mapping. That's literally all of the code. You mean which fields each document has?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Just execute this on Kibana `GET <your_index_name>/_mapping` or in browser `http://<your_host_name>:<port>/<your_index_name>/_mapping?pretty` and just update the question with those details.